# Angular2 renderer setElementClass isAdd options does not work

Tags: angular

Why doesn't this work, as stated in the docs ?

```
renderer.setElementClass(el, 'class1', false); // replace class
renderer.setElementClass(el, 'class2', true); // add a class
```

This results in the element only have the `class2` instead of both.

Reference [Angular2 renderer docs](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html)

Comment: You can see this as **EXPERIMENTAL** so nothing can be questioned on it. We need to wait for the stable release and raise them as issue if any. How ever can you update the code for **el** element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out the `isAdd` option is the equivalent of a remove class, so the following works for toggling classes:

```
renderer.setElementClass(el, 'class1', false); // remove class1
renderer.setElementClass(el, 'class2', true); // add class2
```

Oh, nothing strange about calling a method `setElementClass` for removing it of course...

Answer (score 16):

Just to mention that Renderer is deprecated now, and have been replaced by **Renderer2**. In the **Renderer2** class there are two methods that replace the *setElementClass* of the deprecated Renderer.

- To add a class:

  `renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'popup');`
- To remove a class:

  `renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'popup');`

For more information see: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

For code samples in form of tutorial see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-renderer2
in particular the section of 'addClass / removeClass'

Answer (score 2):

**Renderer class has been removed in version 9 and migrated it to Renderer2**

**In Renderer** ->
`setElementClass(renderElement, className, isAdd)`

**In Renderer2** ->
`isAdd ? addClass(renderElement, className) : removeClass(renderElement, className)`

*In short setElementClass method has been migrated into addClass method and removeClass method based on the third parameter passed in setElementClass.*

- If third parameter is true -> method will be addClass
- If third parameter is false -> method will be removeClass